# Macro Hyper links in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that changes a cell into a hyper link. I want to use the value of the cell in the hyperlink

```
Sub HyperAdd()

'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink

For Each xCell In Selection


    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, _
    Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/=xCell"

Next xCell

End Sub
```

if the cell value is 123 how do i make the anchor link this url http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/123

Comment: Try `Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/" & xCell`

Answer (score 0):

As Fadi points out, the answer to this question is a syntax correction.

Change:

```
Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/=xCell"
```

To be:

```
Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/" & xCell
```

---

---

Excel treats the characters within the quotation marks as a string, so referencing "xCell" entirely within the "http..." string does not work. It will only result in the address being "`http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/=xCell`" every time since Excel will not treat a variable name within a string as a variable.

Instead, the string needs to be appended as shown above so that xCell is used outside of the string, and the value of xCell will be used instead of the text "xCell".

So, if the value of xCell were "abc123", then

```
Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/" & xCell
```

would be:

```
Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/" & "abc123"
```

which becomes:

```
Address:="http://example.ie/booking/viewBooking/abc123"
```